# Changing plot style in PredictorMeasurements

Tags: graphics, machine-learning

I'm trying to combine a `PredictorMeasurements["ComparisonPlot"]` plot with another plot, but the problem is that the plot generated by `PredictorMeasurements` has plot markers that are far too large. Any way to change them?

Comment: `PredictorMeasurements[p, testset, "ComparisonPlot" ]/. PointSize[_]:>PointSize[Tiny]`?

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly. So to be clear, if I want to pass any plot option to the plot, I would use this sort of method? So say I want to  make the points small and red, I would use `PredictorMeasurements[p, testset, "ComparisonPlot" ]/. {PointSize[_]:>PointSize[Tiny],PlotStyle[_]:>PlotStyle[Red]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an example from the docs

```
points = {##, Cos[#1*#2] + RandomReal[{-.2, .2}]} & @@@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1000, 2}];

trainingset = {#1, #2} -> #3 & @@@ points[[;; 800]];
testset = {#1, #2} -> #3 & @@@ points[[801 ;;]];
p = Predict[trainingset];
pm = PredictorMeasurements[p, testset];
cp = pm["ComparisonPlot"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Post-process `cp` to change the directives like `PointSize` and color:

```
cp /. {{dir___, p:Point[___]}:>{dir, PointSize[Tiny], Red, p}, 
      pl:PointLegend[__]:>(pl /. RGBColor[___]:>Red)}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]